# To repeat the article 'a' in this case or not: 'a singer not (a) dancer'

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, repetition

1. He is a singer not dancer.
2. He is a singer not a dancer.

Which one is correct? In this case, 'a' should be repeated or not?

Answer (score 1):

I think that it should be repeated, since "dancer" is a singular count noun, and singular count nouns need a determiner. Therefore,

> He is a singer not a dancer.

Comment: I agree.  However, it strikes me that "We need a singer or dancer to perform at the show next week" sounds fine, and I can't explain exactly why, except to say that the presence of *not* makes a difference.

Comment: @stangdon - Don't you think "We need a singer or a dancer" sounds better?

Comment: @KateBunting I agree that it does, but the article-less dancer still sounds acceptable to me.  This may be a dialect issue!